# Android: tap screen remotely

Tags: android, touch

Is it possible to implement something like this on Android?

Let's say I have an Android device running an app (not mine). It will always be the same app with the same view. I need the device to trigger touch on a specific screen location whenever I need it to.

1. I create a request on the server
2. Android device checks for requests periodically
3. Whenever a new request is found, it touches the screen at X and Y
4. It sends a response that the request is done

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically dispatch touch actions on a view.

```
public void TouchView(View view, Float x, Float y)
{
    view.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.Obtain(SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), (int)MotionEventActions.Down, x, y, 0));
    view.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.Obtain(SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), (int)MotionEventActions.Up, x, y, 0));
}
```

Comment: Can you dispatch actions to another app like this?

Comment: I don't think any process can do this in android.